# Is there a way to optimise for high precision of one class in binary classification?

Tags: classification

binary cross entropy loss function optimises for accuracy, but what if i'm only interested in having high precision (not f1) of one of the two classes?

Comment: post a code please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to tune you model with some sort of grid search CV you need to define your own scoring function which will be the precision for the one class you need.

Using sklearn's confusion matrix the precision of either 0's or 1's can be calculated the following way:

```
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

print("Precision of 0s: {:.2f}".format(conf_mat[0][0]/(conf_mat[:,0].sum())))
print("Precision of 1s: {:.2f}\n".format(conf_mat[1][1]/(conf_mat[:,1].sum())))
```

Then you need to read the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring) in sklearn regarding 3.3.1.2. Defining your scoring strategy from metric functions